# Invalid module format

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, initramfs

I try to install a module using this command:

```
sudo insmod mymod.ko [arg1] [arg2]
```

but I get this error while loading the module:

```
insmod: error inserting 'mymod.ko': -1 Invalid module format
```

my current kernel:

```
uname -r
4.4.6-040406-generic
```

To compile the module for my linux kernel, I downloaded linux 4.4.6 since I couldn't find any source code for 4.4.6-040506-generic. This is the information about the module:

```
modinfo mymod.ko
vermagic:       4.4.6 SMP mod_unload modversions
```

When I try to boot the kernel from the compiled source code, it fails to boot. It stuck with busybox and prompt initramfs.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you include a little bit [more information](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/5419599)?  For example, what command did you use to load the module?

Comment: I used "sudo insmod mymod.ko [arg1] [arg2] "

Comment: Great, could you [edit your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/273521/edit) to include that info?

Answer (score 1):

Run that `insmod` command, and after getting the error you mentioned of invalid module format, run `dmesg` and look at the last 4 lines. Usually it describes in such a case inconsistency between version of the module and version of the running kernel. If you have trouble understanding those lines, post them here.